# How can I change the apperance (text color, line width, etc.) of a legend?

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I tried the following code:

```
x = [1 2];
y = [32 38];
x1 = [1 2];
y1 = [23 27];
x2 = [1 2];
y2 = [30 36];
x3 = [1 2];
y3 = [25 29];
p1=plot(x,y,'-rd','LineWidth',2,'MarkerEdgeColor','k',...
                  'MarkerFaceColor','r','MarkerSize',10);
hold all
p2=plot(x1,y1,'-gp','LineWidth',2,'MarkerEdgeColor','k',...
                    'MarkerFaceColor','g','MarkerSize',10);
p3=plot(x2,y2,'-cs','LineWidth',2,'MarkerEdgeColor','k',...
                    'MarkerFaceColor','c','MarkerSize',10);
p4=plot(x3,y3,'-m^','LineWidth',2,'MarkerEdgeColor','k',...
                    'MarkerFaceColor','m','MarkerSize',10);
xlim([0 3]);
ylim([0 40]);
ax = gca;
c = ax.Color;
ax.YGrid = 'on';
set(gca,'XTick',[0 1 2]);
hYLabel=ylabel('US$');
hXLabel = xlabel('Test');
hTitle=title('Test');
h = get(gca,'Children');
M = {'L1', 'L1 a1 a2', 'L1 b1 b2', 'L1 c1 c2', 'L1 d1 d2'};
hLegend=legend(h,M(2:5),'Location','NorthEast');
set([gca,hTitle,hXLabel,hYLabel,hLegend], 'FontName', 'Helvetica','FontSize', 8); 
set(hTitle,'FontSize', 11);
```

But it doesn't give me the results I want. Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. I want to change the text color of legend and also increase the spacing between the legend.
2. Is there any possibility to change the width of marker edge lines?

**EDIT:**

As per your suggestion I edited the above code:

```
clear all;clf;

x = [1 2];
y = [32 38];
x1 = [1 2];
y1 = [23 27];
x2 = [1 2];
y2 = [30 36];
x3 = [1 2];
y3 = [25 29];
plot(x,y,'-r','LineWidth',2);
p1=plot(x,y,'-rd','LineWidth',1,'MarkerEdgeColor','k',...
                  'MarkerFaceColor','r','MarkerSize',10);
hold all
plot(x1,y1,'-gp','LineWidth',2);
p2=plot(x1,y1,'-gp','LineWidth',1,'MarkerEdgeColor','k',...
                    'MarkerFaceColor','g','MarkerSize',10);
plot(x2,y2,'-cs','LineWidth',2);
p3=plot(x2,y2,'-cs','LineWidth',1,'MarkerEdgeColor','k',...
                    'MarkerFaceColor','c','MarkerSize',10);
plot(x3,y3,'-m^','LineWidth',2);
p4=plot(x3,y3,'-m^','LineWidth',1,'MarkerEdgeColor','k',...
                    'MarkerFaceColor','m','MarkerSize',10);
xlim([0 3]);
ylim([0 40]);
ax = gca;
c = ax.Color;
ax.YGrid = 'on';
set(gca,'XTick',[0 1 2]);
hYLabel=ylabel('US$');
hXLabel = xlabel('Test');
hTitle=title('Test');
h = get(gca,'Children');
M = {'L1','L1 a1 a2', 'L1 b1 b2',   'L1 c1 c2', 'L1 d1 d2'};
[hLegend, hObjects] = legend(h, M(2:5), 'Location', 'NorthEast');
pos = get(hLegend, 'Position');
set(hLegend, 'Position', pos+[-0.02 -0.1 0.02 0.1]);
set(hObjects(6:2:12), 'LineWidth', 1);
set(hObjects(1:4), {'Color'}, {'m'; 'c'; 'g'; 'r'});
set([gca,hTitle,hXLabel,hYLabel,hLegend], 'FontName', 'Helvetica','FontSize', 8); 
set(hTitle,'FontSize', 11);
```

But the legends are messed up. What is wrong with the code? I plotted twice and changed the line width of first line as the width of line and line width of second as the marker edge.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "width of marker"?

Comment: ...I want to reduce the width of the edge of triangle ,rectangle etc

Comment: I updated my answer to address your new errors. Also, in your new code, you should move `hold all` so it is immediately after your first call to plot.

Comment: @gnovice thanks. can you help this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721486/how-to-plot-a-line-chart-from-the-values-of-barchart?noredirect=1#comment74518878_43721486

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, if you want to change the width of the marker edges in the plot, you have to adjust the [`'LineWidth'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/primitiveline-properties.html#property_d0e588387). This affects both the thickness of the marker edges as well as the thickness of the plotted line. If you want these to be set to different thicknesses, you'll have to plot each line twice: once with no markers ([`'Marker'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/primitiveline-properties.html#property_d0e588756) set to `'none'`, the default), and once with only markers ([`'LineStyle'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/primitiveline-properties.html#property_d0e588261) set to `'none'`). If you want to change only the line widths for the *legend*, but *not* the plot, see below.

You can easily change aspects of the legend by capturing the handles to the objects in the legend, which are returned from the [`legend`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html) function. You can change the line in your above code where you create the legend to:

```
[hLegend, hObjects] = legend([p1 p2 p3 p4], M(2:5), 'Location', 'NorthEast');
```

Notice that instead of passing a vector of axes child handles, I'm explicitly passing a vector of the handles returned from the `'plot'` commands. This is necessary if there are other plot objects you don't want in the legend, and to have better control over the order of objects in the legend.

Now that you have handles to the legend objects you can change various aspects of the legend. For example, this will make the legend a bit larger and change the text colors (notice the color order matches the order of the line handle vector passed to `legend`):

```
pos = get(hLegend, 'Position');
set(hLegend, 'Position', pos+[-0.02 -0.1 0.02 0.1]);
set(hObjects(1:4), {'Color'}, {'r'; 'g'; 'c'; 'm'});
```

Also, if you want to change the edge thickness of the legend markers, but not the plot markers, you can do this:

```
set(hObjects(6:2:12), 'LineWidth', 1);
```

And here's the sample image you get from the above (plotting lines and markers separately to adjust the line widths accordingly):

[image]

Comment: ...I want to reduce the width of the edge of triangle ,rectangle etc